# Performance: Fortran 90 argument vs. use module

Tags: optimization, fortran, fortran90

I am often confronted with the question whether it is better to pass large arrays and subsets thereof as arguments or use modules instead. For example:

```
type( plant_type ), dimension( 5, 50000 ) :: plant
```

Note that one dimension is very long and the other much smaller.
The argument that is passed is only a subset of the array:

```
call plantgrowth( plant(:,icell) )
```

Instead of passing this argument , I could also call `plantgrowth()` without the argument by adding a

```
use md_biosphere, only: plant
```

inside the subroutine `plantgrowth()`.

**==> Which option works faster?**

Here are the alternative Fortran examples:

**Using arguments:**

```
module md_biosphere

  implicit none

  private
  public :: biosphere, plant_type  ! only plant_type (not plant) is made public, but not instance of the type ('plant')

  ! the important aspect here is that ncells >> nplant
  integer, parameter :: ncells = 500000
  integer, parameter :: nplant = 50

  type plant_type
    real :: foliage
    real :: roots
    real :: wood
  end type plant_type

  type( plant_type ), dimension( nplant, ncells ) :: plant

contains

  subroutine biosphere()

    integer :: icell

    do icell=1,ncells

      call plantgrowth( plant(:,icell) )

    end do

  end subroutine biosphere


  subroutine plantgrowth( plant )

    type( plant_type ), dimension(nplant), intent(inout) :: plant
    integer :: iplant

    ! more stuff here ...
    do iplant=1,nplant
      plant(iplant)%foliage = 1.0
      plant(iplant)%roots   = 1.0
      plant(iplant)%wood    = 1.0
    end do

  end subroutine plantgrowth


end module md_biosphere

!//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

program example_module

  use md_biosphere, only: biosphere

  implicit none

  call biosphere()

end program example_module
```

**Using 'use module':**

```
module md_biosphere

  implicit none

  private
  public :: biosphere, plant  ! instance 'plant' is made public and does not have to be passed as argument

  ! the important aspect here is that ncells >> nplant
  integer, parameter :: ncells = 500000
  integer, parameter :: nplant = 50

  type plant_type
    real :: foliage
    real :: roots
    real :: wood
  end type plant_type

  type( plant_type ), dimension( nplant, ncells ) :: plant

contains

  subroutine biosphere()

    integer :: icell

    do icell=1,ncells

      ! no arguments are passed
      call plantgrowth( icell )

    end do

  end subroutine biosphere


  subroutine plantgrowth( icell )

    integer, intent(in) :: icell
    integer :: iplant

    ! more stuff here ...
    do iplant=1,nplant
      plant(iplant,icell)%foliage = 1.0
      plant(iplant,icell)%roots   = 1.0
      plant(iplant,icell)%wood    = 1.0
    end do

  end subroutine plantgrowth


end module md_biosphere

!//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

program example_module

  use md_biosphere, only: biosphere

  implicit none

  call biosphere()

end program example_module
```

Comment: *Which option is faster?*  Why don't you tell us what you have measured so far ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark has a good point.
You probably need to get the timing for a single 'plantgrowth'. And it depends on whether there are a lot of things that can be vectorized or not as to whether the order becomes important.

Comment: I compiled (gfortran) and ran the two examples for (ncells, nplant)=(5e5, 50) and (5e4,5) [NOTE THE CORRECTED CODE ABOVE TO MAKE IT RUN]. The results are interesting: When using the large array, passing arguments runs faster than using modules (0.255s vs. 0.289s). For the smaller array it's opposite: 0.010s vs. 0.008s.

Comment: The execution time will also depend on the flags you used. Did you use optimization flags ? I don't think your measurements can be reliable as it is, you should run your simulation for at least several seconds and the same case several times (you can't conclude anything about 0.010s vs 0.008s for a single shot)

Comment: what does "passing arguments" mean when contrasted with "using modules"? What exactly do you intend to be happening with your passing schemes?... Are you passing Values , references or pointers? What do you believe that the module is doing to the executable?  Some large set of runs as @Coriolis mentioned, using the same 5e5,50 versus 50,5e5 seems more inline with the original question.

Comment: I doubt that arguments vs module variables will have a meaningful effect on execution time.  I'd choose based upon program clarity.  Using arguments can clarify the flow of information between routines.  On the other hand, if a variable is used in very many routines, it can be convenient to make it a module variable.